# Strange DWT-controls style

Tags: user-interface, d

I'm using **DWT** from the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/d-widget-toolkit/dwt)  (the latest version) with [recomended](https://github.com/d-widget-toolkit/dwt#building-hello-world) building parameters for **Windows**:

```
dmd "myGuiApp.d" -IC:\\D\\dwt\\imp ^
 -JC:\\D\\dwt\\org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86\\res ^
 -L+C:\D\dwt\lib\ -L+org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86.lib ^
 -L+dwt-base.lib -L/SUBSYSTEM:windows:4
```

The GUI applications may run on **Win XP** and **Win 7**, but the DWT-controls style is like from the older Windows versions like it was on **Win 98** (without color gradient on the buttons, with strict corners). My first idea was to change parametr `SUBSYSTEM` to `windows:5` or `windows:6`, but it didn't help. And I failed to find any mention about similar problems in google.

So maybe anyone knows or guesses, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: One more way to do this will be (as it was mentioned in the end of [this](http://hg.dsource.org/projects/dwt-win/raw-annotate/50ff93cdc412/README.txt) text) to add building parameter (something like) `-L/rc:..\res\resource.res`. The `res` file can be found in `...\dwt\win-res` folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need a manifest for the exe and might have to call InitCommonControlsEx (I don't know if DWT does this or not; I've never actually used it) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775697%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The manifest is explained here, along with an overview of how to do it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The manifest is the XML stuff a bit down on that page. The D compiler doesn't have the pragma to add the xml right in, but you can compile it into a resource file or just name the XML file yourexename.manifest and put it in the same directory as the exe.

From the MSDN link:
"Manifests are written in XML. The name of the application manifest file is the name of your executable followed by the file name extension .manifest; for example, MyApp.exe.manifest. The following sample manifest shows that the first section describes the manifest itself. The following table shows the attributes set by the assemblyIdentity element in the manifest description section."

Comment: Thank you! Your advice was really helpful. I just made the `MyApp.exe.manifest` near the `MyApp.exe` and **rebuilded** the application.